# Node.js - Problems using the SOAP library

Tags: javascript, node.js, wsdl

I am trying to use this package: https://github.com/milewise/node-soap

However, when I do this:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';
var args = {name: 'value'};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.MyFunction(args, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

It returns back: "undefined".

My question is I don't understand when it says "args". Is it to do with the nodes in the WDSL?

The WSDL file is as follows:

```
<xsd:element name="getAllMarkets">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="request" type="types:GetAllMarketsReq"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I had to patch soap.js to get it to work with Betfair API but it's a very ugly hack. Hoping to see some nicer solutions here.

Answer (score 3):

You are logging `result`, which is probably undefined because there's an error, meaning the `err` argument to your callback function IS defined and will have info for you. In this case since it looks like you're calling `MyFunction` instead of `getAllMarkets`, your error will probably be some sort of "Unknown Method" error.  Do `console.log(err, result);` and see what that prints out.

Comment: args should be replaced with an object that matches the structure of {"request":GetAllMarketsReq} as well as calling the correct method.

Answer (score 3):

**instead of this** :

```
var args = {name: 'value'};
```

**try this** :

```
var args = {'tns:name': 'value'};
```

its worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var args = { request: { name: 'value' } };
```